# Using BeautifulSoup to find all elements starting with a given letter

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

If I want to find all <p> elementswith id=test with BeautifulSoup, I use :

```
for item in soup.findAll('p', {"id": "test"}):
```

How do I find every

element with an ID starting with a specific letter - let's say "t"?

I tried "t*" but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 11):

try:

```
import re
for item in soup.findAll('p', {"id": re.compile('^t')}):
```

Answer (score 3):

```
for item in soup.findAll('p', {"id": lambda x: x and x.startswith('t')}):
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for item in soup.find_all('p', id=re.compile('^test')):
```

Comment: What have you changed? Can you add an explanation? Why does this solve the problem of OP?

Comment: Changed function name from Findall to find_all and passes keyword argument id with regular expression as value instead of dictionary.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to remove '}' from my answer. Edited my answer now.

Comment: Ah okay, can you add this additional information in the answer itself? Will be helpful for readers and OP.